git rm --cached <file> - при удалении файла из индекса git (на диске оставляем) с последующим добавлением в .gitignore файл удаляется с диска
Такая ситуация не понятная. Есть сайт site.ru, в нем есть файл, добавленный в индекс git:  site.ru/file.php
Требуется удалить файл из индекса git (удалить из отслеживаемых), но не удалять с диска.
git rm --cached file.php  удаляем файл из кеша git
echo "file.php" >> .gitignore добавляем в список игнорируемых файлов
Комитимся. Все хорошо, файл удалился из индекса git, на диске остался.
Далее возвращаюсь в более старый комит - возвращают в исходный комит и файл пропадает с диска. Хотя как я понимаю не должен
Как его ставить на диске?

"Комитимся" - этот ваш коммит содержит удаление файла. git rm --cached file.php отметило файл как удаленный без удаления с диска, но при применении коммита с такими изменениями он естественно будет удаляться.
